# Is it possible to retrieve an anonymous JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have this code:

```
{a: 42}
```

After this line was executed, I think the object is stored somehow in the memory, I'm wondering how can I get it, in some tricky way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You can't do this.

Any decent js interpreter will destroy it with the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

No: once you lose all references to an object, you cannot recover it and the GC will collect it.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Anonymous objects are *intended* to work this way. If you need to retrieve an object later on, you should simply *name* it. (I assume you are asking this question out of curiosity and not out of neccessity).

As soon as an object has no existing references to it, the garbage collector *should* destroy the object, as is confirmed by [this page](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clAtGb):

> ECMAScript uses automatic garbage
>   collection. The specification does not
>   define the details, leaving that to
>   the implementers to sort out, and some
>   implementations are known to give a
>   very low priority to their garbage
>   collection operations. But the general
>   idea is that if an object becomes
>   un-referable (by having no remaining
>   references to it left accessible to
>   executing code) it becomes available
>   for garbage collection and will at
>   some future point be destroyed and any
>   resources it is consuming freed and
>   returned to the system for re-use.
>
> This would normally be the case upon
>   exiting an execution context. The
>   scope chain structure, the
>   Activation/Variable object and any
>   objects created within the execution
>   context, including function objects,
>   would no longer be accessible and so
>   would become available for garbage
>   collection.